# Python if condition over pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following df:

```
    Date        1a          1b
112 2022-10-17  3.18        2.11
298 2022-10-16  4.26        7.00
340 2022-10-16  11.66       7.80    
379 2022-10-16  15.78       2.13
```

What I want (without a loop) to check for each row the value in 1b is larger than the value in 1a. And if so, I want to add a new column with the difference between the two. So, I want to obtain the following df:

```
    Date        1a          1b     difference
112 2022-10-17  3.18        2.11   0
298 2022-10-16  4.26        7.00   2.74
340 2022-10-16  11.66       7.80   0    
379 2022-10-16  15.78       2.13   0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```py
In [42]: df["1b"].sub(df["1a"]).clip(lower=0)
Out[42]:
112    0.00
298    2.74
340    0.00
379    0.00
dtype: float64
```

- subtract 1a from 1b column
- clip from the lower at 0

  - this means when 1a was greater, result would be negative, and so clamped at 0

to assign to a new column, you can do `df["difference"] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
df['difference']=np.where(df['1b']>df['1a'], df['1b']-df['1a'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) and [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df['difference'] = np.where(df['1b'].le(df['1a']), 0, df['1b'].sub(df['1a']))
```

print(df):

```
           Date     1a    1b  difference
112  2022-10-17   3.18  2.11        0.00
298  2022-10-16   4.26  7.00        2.74
340  2022-10-16  11.66  7.80        0.00
379  2022-10-16  15.78  2.13        0.00
```